# Harmonic conjugate extend to boundary

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

Suppose u is a harmonic function in disc $|z|<1$, and u can be extended continuously to boundary, what about its harmonic conjugate v? Can it also be extended continuous to boundary?

I know v can be represented by integral use the boundary value of u, but I don't think this can help.

Can anyone prove it or give a counterexample? Thank all of you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the real and imaginary parts of a conformal map from the disc to a region such as $-1/(1+y^2) < x < 1/(1+y^2)$.